# SharePoint 2007 onchange event not unbinding in ie6

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, internet-explorer-6

Im confident that this isnt a sharepoint 2007 issue, but id rather cover all of my bases.

I am consulting at a large company, developing a sharepoint solution for their intranet. One of my tasks is to switch the regular dropdownlist in the sharepoint 2007 listview with something that has type ahead and filtering. So i chose a jquery combobox.

Now, in everything but ie6 this combobox works, and the onchange event also works. My process is this:

```
function diidFilterLinkTitleNoMenuOnChange()
{
     FilterField("{9232EB4D-2E5D-40D3-A1C0-818CC21AC839}","LinkTitleNoMenu",this._selOption.value, this.selectedIndex);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
window.dhx_globalImgPath='../_layouts/Intranet.Portal.Custom/PeopleChangesFiles/imgs/';
    var y = document.getElementById('diidFilterLinkTitleNoMenu');
    if(y != null)
    {
          $('#diidFilterLinkTitleNoMenu').change(function(){}).attr('onchange',function(){});


          var z = dhtmlXComboFromSelect('diidFilterLinkTitleNoMenu');
          z.enableFilteringMode(true);
          z.attachEvent("onchange",diidFilterLinkTitleNoMenuOnChange);
          y.parentNode.removeChild(y);       

    }        

    })
```

I am removing the current onchange event before turning the select list into a combobox, then reassigning a different onchange event.

What is happening as far as i can tell in ie6, is that the old onchange event is still there, still attached, and firing first as it breaks the code and my event doesnt run.

Is there a special way in removing events in ie6? Or am i doing this wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because [change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) method is a shortcut for `.bind('change', handler)`. And .bind attaches event handler not removes or overrides.

Quote from [bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) page:

> When an event reaches an element, all handlers bound to that event
>   type for the element are fired. If there are multiple handlers
>   registered, they will always execute in the order in which they were
>   bound.

Use [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) to remove event handlers: `$('#diidFilterLinkTitleNoMenu').unbind('change');`